# no member named 'check' in namespace 'eosio'

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, contract-development

I am trying to build a contract and receiving this error:

```
In file included from /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/bin/../include/eosiolib/contracts/eosio/system.hpp:6:[0K
/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/bin/../include/eosiolib/contracts/eosio/../../core/eosio/time.hpp:157:20: error: no member named 'check' in namespace 'eosio'[0K
eosio::check( std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() - slot >= 1, "block timestamp overflow" );[0K
```

Any idea what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you include more code relating to the contract you are trying to build. Most importantly the header includes you are using. The specific error you are getting here is `no member named 'check' in namespace 'eosio'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to include eosio.hpp before the other includes.

`#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>`

*Sidenote: this actually seems to be a problem with cdt 1.6.1 and will hopefully be fixed with next releases* [Issue#532](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/532)

Comment: Can you add a link to the Github issue for your sidenote if you know it?

Comment: Done. See above.